# Scrape URL of a window with PHP which is recently opened with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, curl

I have a piece of code , which opens a URL with **window.open()** method of JavaScript. What I want to do is , to get the URL of the currently opened page from the opener page. And display that URL in the opener page console. I tried it with JavaScript, using Cookies, Local Storage and postMessage API of JavaScript, but all have the cross origin policy problem. The page I am opening is from my local host and the other page can be any on remote servers, e.g; facebook.com etc. I want to scrape that URL through PHP curl, if possible. My code just work for same origin domains not cross.

**Below is my code which I tried in JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var domain = 'https://localhost.com/files/popup.html';
var myPopup = window.open(domain,'myWindow');


setTimeout(function(){

  console.log('Response : ' + myPopup.document.URL);


},4000);
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at greasemonkey/tampermonkey to run javascript on external webpages.

Comment: You can not get those URLs using normal client-side JavaScript. As soon as you move to a different domain, you loose all access - and for good reason.

Comment: @Calimero I am writing up my own extension , I don't want to use another extension for that

Comment: @CBroe isn't it possible with PHP curl, to scrap that url

Comment: PHP & cURL don’t know of any “popups” ...

Comment: @CBroe is there any solution for getting that URL, even in javascript

Comment: With normal JS that runs in the context of a website: No, of course not.